# SQL Not IN equivalent in CAML

Tags: 2010, caml-query, caml

I have two list(subject, subjectcategory).

subject(ID,Title,CategoryId)

subjectcategory(ID,Title)

I want to create a CAML query for SharePoint that does something like this

```
SELECT     ID, Title
FROM         dbo.SubjectCategory
WHERE     (ID NOT IN
                      (SELECT     CategoryID
                        FROM          dbo.Subject))
```

**Edit**
I use this code

should return the equivalent of

```
WHERE Title IN ([Title1], [Title2],...[TitleN])
```

for get list of title :

```
private string _camlTitleEq = "<Neq>" +
                         "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                         "<Value Type=\"Text\">{0}</Value>" +
                      "</Neq>";

private XElement BuildOrClause(List<string> listItemTitles, int index)
{
 //If we've reached the last item in the list, return only an Eq clause
 if (index == listItemTitles.Count - 1)
 return XElement.Parse(String.Format(_camlTitleEq, listItemTitles[index]));
 else
 {
  //If there are more items in the list, create a new nested Or, where
  BuildOrClause
  XElement andClause = new XElement("And");
  andClause.Add(XElement.Parse(String.Format(_camlTitleEq, listItemTitles[index])));
  andClause.Add(BuildOrClause(listItemTitles, index + 1));
  return andClause ;
}
}
```

and for set query

```
 SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
 string titleIn = BuildOrClause(listItemTitles, 0).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

 query.Query = "<Where>" +
          titleIn +
      "</Where>";
```

Is there any way for it??

Comment: Not an answer, but [CAMLEX.NET](http://camlex.codeplex.com/) provides you an easy way to build such statements. See "Scenario 9. Dynamic filtering conditions"

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this will help you but here are some links that should lead you in the right direction:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341039/does-not-contain-in-caml

and

[Not IN CAML Query](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/not-in-caml-query)

Hope it helps :)