# CAML Query for Values Not "In" (with sufficiently different title to let me post the question)

Tags: 2010, caml-query

I have the following CAML query:

```
<Where>
<In>
  <FieldRef Name='ObjectID' />
  <Values>
    <Value Type='Integer'>71</Value>
    <Value Type='Integer'>72</Value>
  </Values>
</In>
</Where>
```

But what I want in the result set if effectively the negation of that, or items that do not meet the condition.

Is there any way I can achieve this with a relatively simple query.

I'm new to CAML and I can't find anything like a `Not` operator.

I looked at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29170/not-in-caml-query) but it's on 2007, apparently before the `<In>` element was introduced. Apologies for the title, it wouldn't let me post it with a sensible one because of the question linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In is just a short form that saves you from writing a big long `<Or><Eq>`... statement. In your case, you can do `<And><Neq>`...

```
<Where>
   <And>
     <Neq>
       <FieldRef Name='ObjectID' />
       <Value Type='Integer'>71</Value>
     </Neq>
     <Neq>
       <FieldRef Name='ObjectID' />
       <Value Type='Integer'>72</Value>
     </Neq>
   </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Is `<In>` just syntactic sugar then? I assumed it would have better performance than massive nested statements.

Comment: Good question - it looks like IN vs OR in SQL Server doesn't make a difference, so beyond maybe a tiny hit for parsing through more XML it's syntactic sugar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110715/sql-server-select-in-vs-or

Comment: From a SQL performance point of view `<In>` is purely suntactic sugar, but SharePoint can handle a lot more values in `<In>` before it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure any `Not` operator exists, so I guess you have to fetch all IDs and do a `Where`.

However, you can be tricky about it, since IDs generated in SharePoint start from `1` and steadily increment upwards. You can't know the last ID just by counting items, one could delete a bunch in the middle, so you need to:

- Find the ID of last inserted item.
- Create a `<Values>` element containing *all* ids up to the largest ID, except those you don't want.
- Run a CAML with `In`.

I guess this would probably just as slow as a `Where`, or slower. But more fun, and fun is good.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I think it's probably going to have to be something like this, but the only problem is `ObjectID` isn't actually a sharepoint ID field (probably bad name for it). But I should be able to do something along these lines.

Comment: +1 - but I'll leave the question open for a little longer to see if anyone has a more direct solution.

Comment: The column not being ID changes the matter. You could also build a huge CAML by nesting `And` and `Neq`, which again can be made easier through U2U CAML Builder or CodeCaml. But still manual, and quite messy.